How to fix Unable to locate package ubuntudde-dde 24.04 LTS
When i try to install Ubuntu Deepin desktop environment using sudo apt install ubuntudde-dde it shows : E: Unable to locate package ubuntudde-dde
I have installed to ppa using this command sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable but still it's not working.


see this https://launchpad.net/~ubuntudde-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable

As you can see here, the full package list isn't yet available for Ubuntu 24.04.
So you need to wait until the PPA maintainers have added all packages (including ubuntudde-dde) to the Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble) branch.
